# How to implement 1D FFT filter for each horizontal line data from image

Tags: image-processing, opencv, fft

I wish to apply a frequency-domain filter, such as a Low Pass or Band Pass, to each horizontal line of an image. Is this possible using opencv?

Comment: "FFT filter" does not make sense. Neither "passing only needed frequency".

Comment: @leonbloy - It has been over 20 years sinced I messed with FFts, but (I think) I recall that there are many data filters based on transforming data from time domain to frequency domain (using FFT) manipulate the frequency domain data then convert back to time domain (reverse FFT)  
I recall that we called these filters "FFT Filters"

Comment: @erjik - Are you talking about something like a high-pass filter?  
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_pass_filter

Comment: @Michael J - Yes, I actually mean high-pass or low-pass filters.

Comment: @leonbloy - So what is better to say in place of "FFT filter" and "passing only needed frequencies"? Please correct me.

Comment: How about something like this:  
  
I wish to apply a frequency-domain filter, such as a Low Pass or Band Pass, to each horizontal line of an image.  Is this possible using opencv?

Comment: @Michael J : First: FFT is just an algorithm for making a DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform); hence "DFT filter" would make  a slightly better title. Second: every LTI filter (which amounts to a linear convolution) can be described-specified in terms of a frequency response; one (possible) way of implementing that is via a Fourier transform (probably with a FFT algorithm). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084987/low-pass-filter-using-fft-instead-of-convolution-implementation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you will need to elaborate more on your questions. Perhaps, giving some concrete examples.

If I interpret your question as:

You have an image with say 10 x 10

> line 1
>
> line 2
>
> line 3  ...
>
> line 10

You want to apply some filter (Low Pass/Band Pass) on these lines independently.

Then, first you need to design your horizontal filters (in whatever tool you want).

Let's assume (without loss of generality) that you have 2 filters:

Low pass: 1x10 image

Band pass: 1x10 image

Then you can use cv::dft to convert these filters into frequency domain. Also use cv::dft to convert your image into frequency domain. Of course, you should convert individual rows separately. One way to do this is:

```
cv::Mat im = cv::imread('myimage.jpg', 1);
cv::Mat one_row_in_frequency_domain;
for (int i=0; i<im.rows; i++){
  cv::Mat one_row = im.row(i);
  cv::dft(one_row, one_row_in_frequency_domain);

  // Apply your filter by multiplying
}
```

Answer (score 2):

actually it looks like openCV can do that out of the box:
[see here in the manual](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#dft)

> DFT_ROWS performs a forward or inverse transform of every individual row of the input matrix; this flag enables you to transform multiple vectors simultaneously and can be used to decrease the overhead