# How Fast is Convolution Using FFT

Tags: time-complexity, fft, convolution

I read that in order to compute the convolution of two signals x,y (1D for example), the naïve method takes `O(NM)`.

However FFT is used to compute `FFT^-1(FFT(x)FFT(y))`, which takes `O(N log(N))`, in the case where N>M.

I wonder why is this complexity considered better than the former one, as M isn't necessarily bigger than log(N). Moreover, M is very often the length of a filter, which doesn't scale with the signal to be filtered, and will actually provide us with a complexity more similar to `O(N)` than to `O(N^2)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Low pass filter using FFT instead of convolution implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3084987/253056)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fast convolution in the frequency domain is typically more efficient than direct convolution when the size of the filter exceeds a particular threshold. So for relatively small filters direct convolution is more efficient, whereas for longer filters there comes a point at which FFT-based convolution is more efficient. The actual value of m for this "tipping point" depends on a lot of factors, but it's typically somewhere between 10 and 100.